# Pass C array to a objective C method

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays

I want to make an array of integers with as little code as possible and pass that array to an objective C method.

I tried the below. `sequence` starts out as an array and is passed to `setLights:`  but when `sequence` is looked at in the method (via breakpoint) it is no longer an array.

*EDIT: I didnt want to use an NSArray because an NSArray of integers is so verbose:

Using NSArray:

```
NSArray *sequence = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], [NSNumber numberWithInt:4],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5],nil];
```

Using C array:

```
int sequence[6] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

```
- (IBAction)testLights:(id)sender {
    int sequence[6] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    //int *sequence[0][1][2][3][4][5]; //also tried this
    [self setLights:sequence];
}


- (void)setLights:(int *)sequence {

    UIImageView *light=[lgtArray objectAtIndex: sequence[0]];
    light.alpha = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                     animations:^{
                         light.alpha = 1;
                     }completion:nil
     ];


}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: does it help to know that it doesn't change anything that it is an Objective C method... that all Objective C functions are really C functions?

Comment: is there any reason ***NOT*** to use NSArray here?

Comment: Lookup "array decays to pointer" - This must have been answered somewhere ...

Comment: You can use short notation too just in case if you plan to use nsarray as `NSArray *sequence = @[@(0),@(1),@(2),@(3),@(4),@(5)];`

Comment: see Edit, I need and array of integers, a C array seemed like the quickest way to write that. Should I use strings then call integerValue on it when I want to use in in my method later?

Comment: No, just use NSNumbers, which is what the shorthand notation that Janak commented on is.

Comment: Ah i see I saw all the @s and thought they were strings, dindt look close enough

Comment: Is there a similar shorthand for creating an NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this syntax to pass the array:

```
- (void)setLights:(int[] )sequence
```

Comment: Some of the other comments and answers show a better way to do what I need, but this answered my original question best

Comment: @DelightedD0D For what it's worth, I agree with the other guys that you should try to avoid C arrays. If the only reason is verbosity, then you should still use NSArray. If the reason is because a third party library uses this, then maybe you would have to use C arrays.

Comment: Agreed, I ended up going with `NSMutableArray *sequence = [@[@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5]  mutableCopy]; for my actual project.

Comment: @Delighted0D Good decision.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into a bizarre feature of C that has propagated through its variants: the [mostly] equivalence of pointers and arrays.

if you do

```
int *sequence ;
```

then you can do

```
sequence [4] ;
```

or

```
*(sequence + 4)
```

Arrays and points are mostly interchangeable. Arrays in C variants are merely data allocation. Your definition of

```
- (void)setLights:(int *)sequence
```

conveys no information array information. You can still access sequence as though it is an array. setLights simply has no intrinsic information as to how many elements sequence has allocated to it.

The problem here is that your usage of the array in setLights needs to match how you have allotted the data.

If you did

```
sequence [100] = 10 ;
```

it would be syntactically correct but likely to create an error.

Comment: Change `*(sequence + 4]` to `*(sequence + 4)`

Answer (score 1):

Is verbose only if you want. Use literals instead:

```
NSArray *sequence = @[@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5];
```

And access to the value like this:

```
UIImageView *light = lgtArray[[sequence[0] intValue]]];
```

Comment: Can this be done with NSMutableArray? or should I then just do `NSMutableArray *newSequence = [(NSArray*) sequence mutableCopy];`

Comment: Yes, but make a mutable copy before: `NSMutableArray *sequence = [@[@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5] mutableCopy];`